# Is there a way to show text-indent while list-style-position is ‘inside'?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
li {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 32px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-indent: 3em;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>list</li></ul>
```

Here is how list show:

[image]

---

Here is the result what I want:

[image]

---

**Because I want to make the 'order-number' align with the content so I set `list-style-position: inside;`.**

But this style cause the `text-indent` effective for the 'order-number' too.

Is there a way to makes the `text-align` effective for the 'order-number' but `text-indet` invalid?

Or I need to change the way I implement this?

Thank for your help!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/marker/ has some good information on helping you achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corresponding CSS:

```css
ol
{
  margin-left: -3ex;
}

li
{
  padding-left: 3em;
}
```

For a working example, see: https://jsfiddle.net/2adnfp86/

Please note: The ordering numbers are right-aligned. And they may increase. So you need to make sure the `ol` margin matches your needs.

Comment: If I set `text-indent: 2em;list-style-position: inside;text-align: center;` to '<li>' . The ordering number would also affect by `text-indent` style;